# remove duplicates when associated values in other columns are repeated

Tags: python, pandas

I want to delete repeated values in the column called "employee" when the associated values in two columns called "ID" and " Year" are repeated.
For example if this is the DataFrame:

[image]

**This is what i want to get:**

[image]

This is what I have done but it did not work:

```
df.loc[((df["ID"].duplicated()) & (df["year"].duplicated()) ), ["employee"]] = ''
```

I found the value of the "employee" was removed from some cells where it was not supposed to be removed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do

```
df.loc[df[['ID','year']].duplicated(),'employee'] = ''
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `np.where()`.

```
import numpy as np

df['employee'] = np.where(df[['ID','year']].duplicated(), '', df['employee'])
```